# YUI 3 Upload - Select files button not appearing offline

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3

I'm new to YUI, I'm trying the file upload example given in samples. The issue I'm facing is  "Select files" button is not appearing in offline (when not connected to internet) , even though yui-min.js is included.

The relevant portion of my source is here,

```
<LINK href="css.css" rel="stylesheet">     
<LINK href="cssgrids-min.css" rel="stylesheet">     
<LINK href="css(1).css" rel="stylesheet">     
<LINK href="prettify-min.css" rel="stylesheet">     
<LINK href="docs-min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <SCRIPT src="yui-min.js">
    </SCRIPT>
    <DIV id="selectFilesButtonContainer"> 
    </DIV>
    <DIV id="uploadFilesButtonContainer"><BUTTON class="yui3-button" id="uploadFilesButton" 
    style="width: 250px; height: 35px;" type="button">Upload Files</BUTTON>     
    </DIV>
```

I'm able to see the upload button properly , but select files button is not appearing. I've all the required css are in local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copied the latest yui-min.js from build. It is working normal.